# Serialization of Hashmap inside a struct is failing

Tags: rust, serialization, hashmap, serde

I have a struct

```
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Clone, Debug, Default)]
pub struct State {
    pub hash_map: HashMap<String, String>,
}
```

The serialization of this struct is not working.

It follows the stack trace to `collect_map`

```
    fn collect_map<K, V, I>(self, iter: I) -> Result<Self::Ok, Self::Error>
    where
        K: Serialize,
        V: Serialize,
        I: IntoIterator<Item = (K, V)>,
    {
        let iter = iter.into_iter();
        let mut serializer = try!(self.serialize_map(iterator_len_hint(&iter)));
```

and then to

```
 fn serialize_map(self, _len: Option<usize>) -> Result<Self::SerializeMap> {
        unreachable!()
    }
```

in `impl<'a> ser::Serializer for &'a mut Serializer {` where the method is not implemented and it fails.

From my understanding, HashMap<String, String> should work out of the box so I'm not sure what am I missing?

I'm using `serde = { version = "1.0.150", default-features = false, features = ["derive"] }` 
and have tried the troubleshooting as per https://serde.rs/derive.html

Comment: Which data format are you targeting? It might be a limitation of that and not of serde. For example csv is bad in modeling nested structures

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `std` to the `serde` features: `serde = { version = "1.0.150", default-features = false, features = ["derive", "std"] }`

Serde can't implement Serialize/Deserialize to HashMap without the std.